# Проверочное слово к слову разрешается

Tags: орфография

помогите

Comment: А "пожалуйста" Вас говорить не учили?

Comment: И все-таки все помогают, не обращая внимания на оформление просьбы(

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, это непроверяемое, словарное слово. Но исторически ему однокоренное решать, а значит, форма прорЕшивать -однокоренная.

Comment: В данном случае повезло, нет чередования. А вообще-то нельзя проверять безударную гласную глаголами на -ыва (ива). Очень часто происходит чередование. Смотреть - рассматривать, спросить - спрашивать.

Comment: Вызывает сомнение существование слова "прорешивать" – например, Грамота.ру  его не подтверждает. Также по поводу суффикса ЫВА/ИВА: кажется, это касается только чередования А/О, а не Е/И.

Comment: То, что Грамота не подтверждает,- не канон, есть слово прорешать( в словаре синонимов http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/261872/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C )
От него прорешивать. Нельзя проверять О-А глаголами несов. вида с ИВА.В этой парадигме точно нет чередования.Значит, можно. Но вопрос ведь не в этом. В СОВРЕМЕННОМ русском НЕТ проверочного слова, а школьникам нужно проверять имеющимися в активном запасе словами.

Comment: Кстати, бывают исключения и в парадигме с чередованием:В глаголах с общей частью -нима́ть (напр., занимать, донимать, обнимать), которым соответствуют глаголы совершенного вида на -ня́ть (занять, принять, поднять, и т. п.), пишется  буква и. В некоторых глаголах этой группы безударный гласный корня может быть проверен ударным и в формах типа отнимет, поднимет, снимет (это формы глаголов на -нять), редко — в производных словах: снимок, в обнимку
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=30  Так что в данном случае это не запрет.

Comment: Для автора вопроса:  в задании А 14 ЕГЭ это слово все-таки надо будет отнести к непроверяемым.

Comment: Глагол "прорешать" и в Грамоте-ру есть, но это еще не значит, что он образует видовую пару с суффиксом ИВА.Так что задачки можно, и даже нужно, порешивать и прорешивать, но только неофициально.

Answer (score 1):

Это, скорее,  непроверяемое слово, так как трудно найти слово с ударной позицией для Е.

Можно попробовать сделать проверку с помощью этимологии, например: РЕШИТЬ – от праслав. *rešiti и др.русск.  рѣшити  «РАЗВЯЗАТЬ;  отпустить грехи»,  сравнить: развязать себе руки, освободиться от проблемы. Есть еще слова РЕШКА (РЕШЕТО), которые также связаны с вязкой, переплетением. В словаре Даля: "Копье аль решето? Выиграть, или проиграть? от игры в орлянку: копье, лицевая сторона монеты, где некогда чеканился Св. Георгий с копьем; решето, оборотная, с кудрявым вензелем". РЕШЕТО - это нечто "переплетённое".

Answer (score 1):

Мне лично нравится ответ Людмилы. Это, конечно, натянутый вариант подведения под ударение, но мне тоже пришел на ум такой диалог:
 - Ты задачки уже порешал?
 - Нет, сижу, порешиваю потихоньку!